# iPhone application PayPal Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, in-app-purchase

I want to add Paypal payment to my iPhone application in this when user make a payment successfully then we will send a music CD by courier to user?
Will apple approve the app if the payment transaction will be done within application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple will block your app only if you are accepting donations via your App. You can sell products and accept payments through your App. It is absolutely legal. There are many apps that do payments via PayPal.eg:- Depop